# Why do I need to import Vue in my .d.ts file?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I don't understand why do I need to import Vue in my .d.ts file? I find "Make sure to import 'vue' before declaring augmented types" in official website.But why need to do this. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins

sometimes, I don't import Vue in my .d.ts files, but no error was reported. I glanced at the many articles, but didn't find the answer

Answer (score 1):

What vue is wanting you to do is to merge the class and interface together. In a way, its like extending the `Vue` class with your own properties.

An easy example would be something like this:

```js
class Car {
  wheels: number;
}

interface Car {
  doors: number;
}
```

Now when you instantiate this `Car` object you can see it will have both a `doors` and a `wheels` property.

```js
const car = new Car();
car.wheels = 4; // no type error
car.doors = 2; // no type error
```

All this is well and good, until you try and do something more complex like add a method to the interface `Car`. Then you will get an error because interfaces cant hold implementations, just structures.

As the article you linked mentioned, to solve this, typescript has [type augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).

By importing the `Car` class, then declaring a module of the same name, you merge together the two `objects`:

```js
import Car from "./car";

declare module "./car" {
  // Now add the interface
  interface Car {
    doors: number;
    drive(distance: number): number;
  }
}
```

Now this doesn't allow you to add implementation into an interface, but what it does do is expose the objects *prototype* where you can now add the implementation details, before you could not.

```js
Car.prototype.drive = function(distance) {
  // move `distance` spaces and return new location
}
```

The reason you did not see an error when you left out the import statement was because, to TypeScript, you have given it a module `Vue` and until you try to access something that the import would have given you there is no error.