# Error Property 'user_id' does not exist when declaring a new attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am doing a typescript and nodejs practice, but I am having an error when declaring a new attribute for request, because it gives me the following error Property 'user' does not exist, i have a src folder, types with a file express.d.ts, with the following code:

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    user_id: number;
  }
}
```

Y con tsconfig.json:

```
"typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types"
]
```

I get the following error, error TS2339: Property 'user_id' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.

Comment: are you wanting to [augment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) the native `Request` object with your own properties? [Does this answer help you?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75292506/9583747)

Answer (score 0):

In the root directory(where src folder exists) create @types/express/index.d.ts file. Inside write the following:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      user_id: number
    }
  }
}
```

You will be able to use req.user_id in your application in src folder